# Uploading multiple files to a single row parse.com

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

So I'm using the following code to upload multiple files to a single row of a class.

```
for (NSString* currentString in directoryContents){

    NSLog(@"%@",currentString);
    NSString *temp2 = [temp stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentString];
    PFFile *file = [PFFile  fileWithName:currentString contentsAtPath:temp2];
    [file saveInBackground];
    PFObject *obj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"DreamBits"];

    if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"index.html"]) {
        [obj setObject:file forKey:@"index"];
    }
    else {
        count += 1;

        NSString *filen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%i",count];
        NSLog(@"%@",filen);

        [obj setObject:file forKey:filen];
    }
    [obj saveInBackground];
}
```

The issue is I'm getting [the files in different rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZtdl.png) for some reason. Any idea how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am modified your code little bit. I am not run this code but hope it helps you.

```
PFObject *obj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"DreamBits"];

    for (NSString* currentString in directoryContents){

        NSLog(@"%@",currentString);
        NSString *temp2 = [temp stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentString];
        PFFile *file = [PFFile  fileWithName:currentString contentsAtPath:temp2];

            if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"index.html"]) {
                [obj setObject:file forKey:@"index"];
            }
            else {
                count += 1;

                NSString *filen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%i",count];
                NSLog(@"%@",filen);

                [obj setObject:file forKey:filen];
            }
    }

    [obj saveInBackground];
```

Create the PFObject outside the loop.Set all the PFFile object to the PFObject inside the loop.

After loop, save the PFObject. It is better to use the method :

```
        [obj saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
               //Check whether the upload is succeeded or not
        }];
```

Comment: You also need to wait for the file saves to finish before attaching them to the object, which is a little bit harder in Objective-C without Promises.

Comment: @TimothyWalters Yes, I agree.File must be uploaded before attached to the PFObject.And it is difficult to keep track of multiple file. Because of this reason,I am not upload the file individually.In above code PFFile will be uploaded as part of the save operation on the PFObject.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method for upload profile and thumb image in a row in the Parse Server table. Using swift 4 and Parse SDK 1.17.1. Hope this technic will help.

```
   func uploadImage(profileImage: UIImage, profileImageName: String, thumbImage: UIImage, thumbImageName: String) {

    if let profileImagefile = PFFile.init(name: profileImageName, data: profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!) {
        let fileObject = PFObject(className:"ProfileImage")
        fileObject.setValue(profileImagefile, forKey: "profile_image")
        fileObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("thumb image path: \(profileImagefile.url ?? "")")
                if let thumbImage = PFFile.init(name: thumbImageName, data: thumbImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!) {
                    fileObject.setValue(thumbImage, forKey: "thumb_image")
                    fileObject.saveInBackground(block: { (result, fileError) in
                        if fileError == nil {
                            print("thumb image path: \(thumbImage.url ?? "")")
                        }else {
                            print("error on thumb upload: \(result)")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }else {
                print("error on file upload: \(error.debugDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```